# Difference between eval() and eval`` (with backticks)

Tags: javascript, string, templates

So I have came across a curious question that I can't find its answer anywhere and there isn't much documentation on what eval does when you pass to it string literals.

If I do `eval("alert(1)")` I will get an alert box with 1, however, when I do `` eval`alert(1)` ``  I just get an array with "alert(1)" I am not sure where that is coming from, isn't it supposed to be treated the same as the previous example?

Also, `` eval`${1}` `` returns an array with two empty elements, why?

Answer (score 1):

What you're running into is something to do with [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates).

Essentially, you are doing string interpolation and using a function to decide how to create the string. The first argument is expected to be an `Array` that contains all of the string parts (everything between `${var}` declarations). The return of any function used this way is expected to be the string. The reason you are seeing 2 entries is because this function returns a raw format in addition to the one it tried to create using the tag function.

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, there is something that I still don't get, why the 2nd element in the returned array is empty, shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: So this is an oddity to do with how Chrome displays results, and something I wasn't expecting. If you save the results of that eval statement to a variable, it returns an array. The `raw` item I mentioned is a property of the Array itself (which is the unexpected part). You should only see 1 entry in reality, it just appears that way initially in Chrome's debugger.